# How to run liquibase as a pre-install hook in Helm?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, liquibase, kubernetes-helm

I have a Springboot microservice which uses `liquibase` for database migrations. However, sometimes the application pod fails to start due to liquibase lock issues `waiting for db lock` in Kubernetes.

In order to avoid this, how can I use Helm's `pre-install hook`?
How to set up a database migration job in `helm`, for spring boot application with liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

Not a helm expert, I used [helm hook documentation](https://docs.harness.io/article/qk178jyns7-use-helm-chart-hooks-in-kubernetes-deployments) a basis.  I am also using [this](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) following definition of the pre-install hook:

> Executes after templates are rendered, but before any resources are
> created in Kubernetes

I think I could have a hook snippet like this in my helm job:

```
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
```

...

```
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: pre-install-job
    command: command: ['sh', '-c', 'liquibase update']
```

Seems like that chart would run the liquibase update command in the pre-install hook.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I didnt get a proper way to do it. So as a workaround, I created another application class(pre install hook) which will run only the spring context and disabled spring.liquibase in main deployment file.